# Missing JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql from spring-social-showcase

Tags: spring, spring-social

I have downloaded spring-social-showcase from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples). In the spring-social-showcase project there is a file MainConfig.java with following database populator code:

```
private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql", JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.class));
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("Account.sql", JdbcAccountRepository.class));
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data.sql", JdbcAccountRepository.class));
    return populator;
}
```

It mentions 3 sql files "JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql","Account.sql" and "data.sql". I found the two except JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql.
Any clue where is "JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql" ?

Comment: It is part of Spring Social itself. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/spring-social-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/social/connect/jdbc/JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql .

Comment: Thanks Deinum. I also found out that the JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql is part of the spring social core module.